# How Objective-C singleton should implement init method?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I read a couple of amazing resources on singletons in Obj-C:

1. SO question: [What does your Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)
2. Friday Q&A: [Care and Feeding of Singletons](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html)
3. Apple docs: [Creating a Singleton Instance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32)

but none of these resources addressed `init` method concept **explicitly** and while still being a novice to Obj-C I'm confused how should I implement it.

So far I know that having `init` private is not possible in Obj-C as it does not offer true private methods... so it's possible that user can call `[[MyClass alloc] init]` instead of using my `[MyClass sharedInstance]`.

What are my other options? I believe I should also handle subclassing scenarios of my singleton.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, an easy way around the `init` is to just not write one to have it call the default NSObject implementation (which only returns `self`). Then, for your `sharedInstance` function, define and call a private function that performs init-like work when you instantiate your singleton.  (This avoids user accidentally re-initializing your singleton.)

***However!!!*** The major problem is with `alloc` being called by a user of your code!  For this, I personally recommend Apple's route of overriding `allocWithZone:` ...

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self sharedInstance] retain];
}
```

This means the user will still get your singleton instance, and they can mistakenly use as if they allocated it, and safely release it once since this custom alloc performs a retain on the singleton.  (Note: `alloc` calls `allocWithZone:` and does not need to be separately overridden.)

Hope that helps!  Let me know if you want more info~

**EDIT: Expanding answer to provide example and more details --**

Taking Catfish_Man's answer into consideration, it's *often* not important to create a bulletproof singleton, and instead just write some sensible comments in your headers/documentation and put in an `assert`.

However, in my case, I wanted a thread-safe lazy-load singleton--that is, it does not get allocated until it needs to be used, instead of being automatically allocated on app launch.  After learning how to do that safely, I figured I may as well go all the way with it.

**EDIT#2:** I now use GCD's `dispatch_once(...)` for a thread-safe approach of allocating a singleton object only once for lifetime of an application. See [Apple Docs: GCD dispatch_once](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once). I also still add `allocWithZone:` override bit from Apple's old singleton example, and added a private init named `singletonInit` to prevent it from accidentally being called multiple times:

```
//Hidden/Private initialization
-(void)singletonInit 
{
   //your init code goes here
}

static HSCloudManager * sharedInstance = nil;   

+ (HSCloudManager *) sharedManager {                                   
    static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;                  
    dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{                           
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];          
        [sharedInstance singletonInit];//Only place you should call singletonInit 
    });                                                                
    return sharedInstance;                                                       
}

+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    //If coder misunderstands this is a singleton, behave properly with  
    // ref count +1 on alloc anyway, and still return singleton!
    return [[HSCloudManager sharedManager] retain];
}
```

`HSCloudManager` subclasses `NSObject`, and does not override `init` leaving only the default implementation in `NSObject`, which as per Apple's documentation only returns self.  This means `[[HSCloudManager alloc] init]` is the same as `[[[HSCloud Manager sharedManager] retain] self]`, making it safe for both confused users and multi-threaded applications as a lazy-loading singleton.

As for your concern about user's subclassing your singleton, I'd say just comment/document it clearly.  Anyone blindly subclassing without reading up on the class is *asking* for pain!

**EDIT#3:**  For **ARC compatibility**, just remove the retain portion from  the `allocWithZone:` override, but keep the override.

Comment: @yAaak, seems fair enough, but I feel like in infinite loop and need to digest it ;) How do I ensure the creating process of such singleton via private method is thread-safe? Other issue: if I follow Apple's `allocWithZone` idea, default NSObject's `init` will be called (does is just return `self` or does sth else?)... and than again user tries to instantiate with `alloc` and `init` does it change anything about my properties/ivars initialization and NSObject getting `init` again?

Comment: yAak, you're right: sane approach you're suggesting such suffice for now. I'll play with singletons a bit more using your code :) I think your answer is quite extensive and takes into account Catfish_man's counter-opinion, so I'm accepting it. Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest dispatch_once() rather than OSAtomic*. Less finicky, just as fast or faster.

Comment: if we call the [alloc] init], the init method would be called twice (One with the sharedManager method implementation and another with the init itslef)? Is that ok?... basically what i am seeing is [[[super allocWithZone:NULL] init] init];

Comment: @grisleyB Yes, it's safe provided you did not implement any `init` methods in your singleton or its super classes. NSObject's `init` is empty. (This is why I suggest using a private `+[singletonInit]` method.) But, despite that being safe, if you know it's a singleton you shouldn't ever call `[[.. alloc] init]` anyway -- use its `+[sharedInstance]` method.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly? The whole fad of writing bulletproof singleton classes seems pretty overblown to me. If you're seriously that concerned about it, just stick assert(sharedInstance == nil) in there before you assign to it the first time. That way it'll crash if someone uses it wrong, promptly letting them know they're an idiot.

Comment: Partially I agree, but other half of me says: why compromise? However I'll go for what I can achieve plus clear comments in header/docs.

Answer (score 2):

The `init` method should not be affected. It will be the same in a singleton class as in a regular class. You may want to override `allocWithZone:` (which is being called by `alloc`) to avoid creating more than one instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

To make the init/new methods unavailable for callers of your singleton class you could use the NS_UNAVAILABLE macro in your header file:

```
- (id)init NS_UNAVAILABLE; 
+ (id)new NS_UNAVAILABLE; 

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
```