# Avoiding singletonton abuse in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have created a singleton:

```
+(instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone
{
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Please use getSharedInstance class method of MotionManager to avoid singleton abuse. =)");

    return nil;
}


+ (id) getSharedInstance
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Why does the above works fine, but the below one throws exception?

```
+(instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone
{
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Please use getSharedInstance class method of MotionManager to avoid singleton abuse. =)");

    return nil;
}


+ (id) getSharedInstance
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = [[super alloc] init];
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to create a singleton:

```
+ (id)sharedManager {


    static Singleton *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];

    });

    return sharedManager;
}
```

Comment: If someone by mistake does not use sharedManager method of yours and does alloc init, it wont be a singleton anymore...

Comment: This question addresses your comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274360/how-objective-c-singleton-should-implement-init-method

Answer (score 1):

This is because `alloc` is also calling `allocWithZone:` internally, see [NSObject doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc)

That's the reason why your code `instance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];` works while `instance = [[super alloc] init];` doesn't.

Comment: So alloc calls the ovveridern allocwithzone in my code but [super allocWithZone:] does not ?

Comment: No, seams you didn't understand the inheritance. `super` will call your `allocWithZone:` because you override it. You call `super alloc`, `super alloc` calls your `allocWithZone:`. When you call `super allocWithZones` it will not call your `allocWithZone:`