# Use new in implementation despite '__attribute__((unavailable))' in header

Tags: objective-c

I have a header for an object that has new marked as unavailable and that is correct (as it should be a singleton)

```
@interface Manager : NSObject <NSCopying>

+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end
```

....... now this is correct for the outside but the @implementation of Manager itself should be exempt from this .... I want it to be able to call `[self new]`

e.g. I want

```
@implementation Manager 

+ (instancetype)shared {
    static id shared = nil;
    if(!shared) {
        shared = [self new];
    }
    return shared;
}
@end
```

---

**Please note this is an example and this NOT about singletons.** I want to call new even though it is forbidden and above was an example

#### possible solutions:

1. so can I somehow override the unavailability attribute? (preferred)
2. is it safe to just call `[super new]`

Comment: this is completely different than what matt told me is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274360/how-objective-c-singleton-should-implement-init-method

Comment: I know how to implement a singleton - the title IS important, singleton is a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast to `id`, then you can send the message `new` without problems:

`shared = [(id)self new];`

You can also use `[super new]` if your class has no implementation of `new`.

Comment: OMG - I totally forgot about just casting to silence the compiler! :D Thanks - Awesome